# Weird symbols when printing char array

Tags: c, string, binary

Ok, so I wrote simple program in C to convert number from decimal to binary and it works just fine until I try to convert 128. Some weird symbols come up and it probably has something to do with ASCII. Could someone explain as why this is happening with numbers 128 and above. Here is my code and image;
[image: screenshot from terminal]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    int a = 128;
    int counter = 0;
    char array[512];
    char c;

    while(a!=0){
        c = a%2 + '0'; // Gives me eather 1 or 0 and converts to char
        array[counter] = c;
        a /= 2;
        counter++;
    }
    for(int i=strlen(array)-1; i>=0; i--){
        printf("%c", array[i]); //printing in reverse
    }
    printf("\n");



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strlen` expects ASCIIZ string, your char array is not null-terminated

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works when i put '\0' at the end. Sow why does it even work for numbers less than 128? @Lashane

Comment: it was undefined behavior, so just luck